# "while" loop exiting prematurely (python 3)

Tags: python

The while loop only runs once and exits as though the condition has been met, however, when debugging for whether the condition has been met externally (after the loop) it has not.

Here is my code:

```
iFile = open("snakein.txt")
line = iFile.readline()
finXStr,finYStr = line.split()

finX = int(finXStr)
finY = int(finYStr)



moves = []

snkX = 0
snkY = 0

while snkX != finX and snkY != finY:
    if finX > 0 and finX != snkX:
        moves.append("R")
        snkX += 1
        print("x moves")
    elif finX < 0 and finX != snkX:
        moves.append("L")
        snkX -= 1
        print("x moves")
    elif finX == snkX:
        moves.append("L")
        snkX -= 1
        print("x moves")
    if finY < 0 and moves[-1] == "R":
        moves.append("R")
        snkY -= 1
        print("y moves")
    elif finY < 0 and moves[-1] == "L":
        moves.append("L")
        snkY -= 1
        print("y moves")
    elif finY > 0 and moves[-1] == "R":
        moves.append("L")
        snkY += 1
        print("y moves")
    elif finY > 0 and moves[-1] == "L":
        moves.append("R")
        snkY += 1
        print("y moves")
    elif finY == snkY:
        moves.appebd("L")
        snakeY -= 1
        print("y moves")

output = moves

oFile = open("snakeout.txt", "w")
oFile.write(str(output))
```

The program is trying to make a "snake" move in the most efficient way to a specific target via certain moves, on a "cartesian plane" like setting.

Comment: What's in the input file?  Before the loop starts, do `finX` and `finY` have the values you expect?

Comment: yes, I have checked that

Comment: This code snippet is not complete, since you do not tell us the contents of file `snakein.txt`. Please give us a complete snippet that we can run, according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `while snkX != finX or snkY != finY:` might make more sense in your context...